# Eliminate characters before a pattern in R

Tags: r, regex

If I have the following dataframe:

```
Fruits
ONE_APPLE
TWO_BANANAS
THREE_ORANGES
FOUR_PINAPPLES
```

Is it possible to delete everything before the underscore, getting as a result:

```
Fruits
APPLE
BANANAS
ORANGES
PINAPPLES
```

There may be a pattern matching function but I haven't find the right one.

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try the below `gsub` command to remove all the characters before `_`(including the symbol `_`)

```
gsub(".*_", "", Test)
```