# How to remove everything before comma in string?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with geographical data, and have a string column in my data which lists a state name, followed by a comma, followed by a county name. How can I eliminate everything before the comma?

So this:

```
Obs    county
1      wisconsin, waukesha
2      oklahoma, tulsa
3      alabama, shelby
4      virginia, montgomery
```

Should become this:

```
Obs    county                     newcounty
1      wisconsin, waukesha         waukesha
2      oklahoma, tulsa              tulsa
3      alabama, shelby              shelby
4      virginia, montgomery        montgomery
```

I understand similar questions to this one have been asked in the past, but all the questions on stack have been asking to delete everything after the comma as opposed to before.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297859/remove-all-text-before-colon  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64341291/how-to-remove-all-text-before-a-pattern  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704213/remove-part-of-a-string  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274010/delete-parts-of-a-character-vector/46274024  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185071/remove-everything-before-period https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24400094/eliminate-characters-before-a-pattern-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can match characters (`.*`) till the `,` followed by zero or more space (`\\s*`) and replace with blank (`""`) in `sub` from `base R`

```
df1$newcounty <- sub(".*,\\s*", "", df1$county)
```

-output

```
df1
#  Obs               county  newcounty
#1   1  wisconsin, waukesha   waukesha
#2   2      oklahoma, tulsa      tulsa
#3   3      alabama, shelby     shelby
#4   4 virginia, montgomery montgomery
```

---

Or another `base R` option is `trimws`

```
trimws(df1$county, whitespace = ".*,\\s*")
#[1] "waukesha"   "tulsa"      "shelby"     "montgomery"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Obs = 1:4, county = c("wisconsin, waukesha", 
     "oklahoma, tulsa", 
"alabama, shelby", "virginia, montgomery")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `strsplit()` in this way:

```
#Code
df$newcounty <- lapply(strsplit(df$county,split = ','), function(x) trimws(x[[2]]))
```

Output:

```
df
  Obs               county  newcounty
1   1  wisconsin, waukesha   waukesha
2   2      oklahoma, tulsa      tulsa
3   3      alabama, shelby     shelby
4   4 virginia, montgomery montgomery
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Obs = 1:4, county = c("wisconsin, waukesha", "oklahoma, tulsa", 
"alabama, shelby", "virginia, montgomery")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```